# Alternative To SQLite Asset Helper Library

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'll begin with explaining how I stumbled upon SQLite Asset Helper library. I am trying to build a small android application which is basically shows the meaning of words. And to do so I intend to keep everything offline (no dependence of internet connectivity). Now, as far as I can think of, there are 2 ways of achieving that:
 1. Using String array, which I believe will be a tedious task and a memory hog.
 2. By providing a pre-populated database, using which I can easily establish relations between words and their meanings and do more (searching, sorting, etc).

Now, the problem I am facing is supplying a pre-populated database (or words and meanings) with the app itself. And for doing that I came across SQLite Asset Helper which does the job.

I have read a number of articles related to SQlite Asset Helper but not many which confirm its implementation on latest iterations of Android. Also, is the only possible solution to deliver a pre-populated database to the user (without needing to go online)? Is it acceptable method? Any other better alternative up for suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have read a number of articles related to SQlite Asset Helper but not many which confirm its implementation on latest iterations of Android

It works on the latest iterations of Android.

> Also, is the only possible solution to deliver a pre-populated database to the user (without needing to go online)?

You are welcome to roll your own implementation. I do not know what you would gain by this.

> Is it acceptable method?

I am not aware of anything better.